# Using scipy.linalg.solve with symmetric coefficient matrix (assume_a='sym')

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve a system of linear equations A * x = b for the unknown x using scipy's [linalg.solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) function. Here is an example that works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as linalg

A = np.array([[ 0.18666667, 0.06222222, -0.01777778],
              [ 0.01777778, 0.18666667,  0.01777778],
              [-0.01777778, 0.06222222,  0.18666667]])
b = np.array([0.26666667, -0.26666667, -0.4])
x = linalg.solve(A, b, assume_a='gen')
```

It results in `x = [1.77194417, -1.4555256, -1.48892533]`, which is a correct solution. This can be verified by computing `A.dot(x)`, which results in `[0.26666667, -0.26666667, -0.4]`. As this is the same as `b`, the solution is correct.

However, the matrix of coefficients `A` is symmetrical, i.e., the values above and below the main diagonal are the same. If I understand the documentation correctly, for solving such a problem more efficiently, the `solve` function allows to set the argument `assume_a='sym'`. Unfortunately, using the following code (given the same `A` and `b`) results in an incorrect solution being found:

```
x = linalg.solve(A, b, assume_a='sym')
```

It results in `x = [1.88811181, -1.88811181, -1.78321672]`, which is different from the solution above. Computing `A.dot(x)` results in `[0.26666667, -0.35058274, -0.48391607]`. As this is different from `b`, the solution seems to be incorrect.

I am wondering, if there is any problem with my code, or if my understanding of symmetric matrices or the expected result is simply wrong!? Maybe the matrix must satisfy additional constraints to be used together with `assume_a='sym'`?

I appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, the matrix as written does not appear to be symmetrical: elements in the (0,1) and (1,0) positions are not equal, nor are the elements in the (1,2) and (2,1) positions.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. They matrix is not symmetrical. It seemed to be at first sight. If I switch the elements at positions (1, 0) and (2, 1) both approaches result in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

In think it won't happen. I provide a short answer about it.

#### Non-symmetric A

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as linalg

A = np.array([[ 0.18666667, 0.06222222, -0.01777778],
              [ 0.01777778, 0.18666667,  0.01777778],
              [-0.01777778, 0.06222222,  0.18666667]])
b = np.array([0.26666667, -0.26666667, -0.4])
x = linalg.solve(A, b, assume_a='gen')
np.allclose(A @ x,b)
```

Out:

> True

Which shows the solver works well.

#### Symmetric A

```
# use you upper triangular A to get a symmetric matrix
A_symm = (np.triu(A) + np.triu(A).T -np.diag(A.diagonal()))

# solve the equations
x = linalg.solve(A_symm, b, assume_a='sym')
np.allclose(A_symm @ x,b)
```

Out:

> True

It still works.

If you pass a non-symmetric matrix `A` to the solver , and then specify the `assume_a = 'sym'`, solver **will only use upper triangular matrix** of `A`, see below:

```
x = linalg.solve(A, b, assume_a='sym')
np.allclose(A @ x,b),x
```

Out:

> (False, array([ 1.88811181, -1.88811181, -1.78321672]))

The result shows that solver works "wrong", but the result `x` is the same with result of `linalg.solve(A_symm, b, assume_a='sym')`